# Are there any angles for which cos and cosec give same values?

Tags: trigonometry

I was doing a physics problem, on solving it with two different methods, I got $$F(Force) = mg\cos(Q)$$ and $$F=\frac{mg}{\sin(Q)}$$ 
($Q$ is an angle), $m=$ mass of the body (constant), $g=$ gravitational acceleration (constant). $Q=\theta$(angle)
Since the Forces are equal, this means
$$\cos Q=\csc Q$$

Answer (score 3):

We note that
$$ \cos Q = \csc Q $$
holds if and only if
$$ \cos Q \sin Q = 1, $$
which holds if and only if
$$ 2 \cos Q \sin Q = 2, $$
or
$$ \sin 2Q = 2, $$
which is clearly impossible.

Comment: +1. Unless $Q$ is complex valued

Answer (score 0):

Cosine never equals cosecant. First, the former must have absolute value $\le 1$, while the latter must have absolute value $\ge 1$. This means that if the cosine of an angle were equal to the cosecant, then they must either both equal $1$ or both equal $-1$, and the sine (yes, ***sine***, not ***sign***) of the angle must also be equal to that same value. But then, $1^2+1^2=1+1=2$ and $(-1)^2+(-1)^2=1+1=2$ both contradict the Pythagorean trigonometric identity.